# How to detect that CLR stops a background thread

Tags: c#, multithreading, clr, background-thread

When all foreground threads are gone, CLR stops the background threads. That can be read a lot. But what I want to know is how the background thread or the application can detect this situation.

Why? I consider it a bad style to let background threads be killed automatically by some CLR magic, so I normally write code to ensure that a thread gets terminated in a ordered way. But failing to do so, would hang the application in the process of being terminated. So I am considering to mark my worker threads as "background", to avoid the hang, but I still want to know that it happens, so that I can fix that bug.

Is there some equivalent to a `ThreadAbortException` that I can catch in the thread main method or some handler I can register?

Comment: Use a background worker and capture the end event.

Comment: How do I "capture the end event"???

Comment: It is "rude abort", no notification provided.  If you properly tell worker threads to terminate and wait for them to oblige then it doesn't matter if it is a foreground or background thread.  Deadlock is a bug you shouldn't try to hide.

Comment: Yea, "avoiding to hide" is the purpose of my question...

Comment: See : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.runworkercompleted?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: Implement IDisposable interface maybe ? And override the Dispose() method ?